# Jest exceed timeout when using fake timers

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest, timeout

I am writing jest test for search input and it give me an error that timeout is exceeded when i am using fake timers. I was trying to increase timeout but received the same error
I have looked into debug and it just stuck after runAllTimers forever

Error message : "**Error: thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test**."

html

```
<lightning-input
        label="Search"
        type="search"
        value={searchCriteria}
        onchange={onChangeSearchCriteria}
></lightning-input>
```

js

```
onChangeSearchCriteria(event) {
    if (this.timeout) clearTimeout(this.timeout);

    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        //eslint-disable-line
        this.handleChangeSearchCriteria(event.detail.value);
    }, 500);
}
```

test.

```
      it("search criteria changed", async () => {
    
            const element = createElement('c-test-lwc', {
                is: testLwc,
            });
            document.body.appendChild(element);
    
    
                jest.useFakeTimers();
    
                const searchInput = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("lightning-input");
    
                searchInput.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', {detail: {value: 'test'}}));
                jest.runAllTimers();
```

Comment: Why are you returning a promise from your test? I think that might be the issue

Comment: @TemporaryFix I thought it may help somehow and forget to remove. Thanks, but its anyway doesnt work.